# Help with code coverage for Attachment Trigger

Tags: unit-test

Here is my trigger (66% Code Coverage):

```
trigger CheckAttachment on Attachment (before insert)
{
  if(trigger.isinsert){
  for (Attachment a : Trigger.new){       
    List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> co = [select id,Attachment_Added__c from BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c where id =: Trigger.New[0].ParentId];         
    If(co.size()>0)         
    {             
    co[0].Attachment_Added__c = True; //This is the section that I need help with code coverage.         
    update co;   //This is the section that I need help with code coverage.               
     }
      }
       }
         }
```

Below is my test class that I need help with:

```
@isTest
public class CheckAttachmentTest {
public static void testAttachment(){
    Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert acct;
    Attachment att = new Attachment();
    Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Test Data'); 
     att.Name = 'Unit Test Attachment';
     att.Body =  b;
     att.ParentID =  acct.Id;
     att.ContentType = 'application/msword';
     att.Description = 'Test, please disregard';
     att.IsPrivate = false;
    insert att;
    List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=: acct.id];
    System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());
      }
        }
          }
```

Comment: How is BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c related to Attachment?  What role does Account play in this?

Comment: Account is a dummy account for testing.  Attachment is a cross object from Incident object.  Trigger is to check attachment object and check box the Attachment Added field in Incident object.

Comment: In order to get coverage you need to create a BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c sObject in your Test class and associate it to the Attachment. Then use that relation in the Trigger to get the BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c record.

Comment: Added code examples for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not getting code coverage for those two lines is because your query is not returning any records.

Your query has several problems. Mainly that you are querying your BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c sObject and filtering by Id.  This will be the Id of the BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c sObject itself, however the Attachment.ParentId is referencing an Account sObject, so it will never return anything.

Another problem with your query is that it is not bulkified.  Using `Trigger.New[0]` is bad practice because if more than 1 record is inserted in one context (such as inserting many records using Dataloader) you will only get the first record.

Also in your Trigger you have an `update` statement inside a for loop.  This is another thing you should never do.  Again if someone were to do a mass insert this could easily cause you to exceed governor limits.  You should add modified records to a list and pull the `update` outside of the for loop, and update the list there.

In order to get coverage you need to create a BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c sObject in your Test class and associate it to the Attachment.  Then use that association in the Trigger to get the BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c record.

Below is how I would modify your code.  Since you're new to Apex, and presumably programming, I've added comments that should help explain things.

```
// Rename the Trigger
// You only want 1 Trigger per object, because if there is
// more than 1 you cannot control the order in which they execute.
trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment (before insert)
{
    // Check both Insert/Update AND Before/After for more control
    // Since you are not updating the Attachment sObject itself
    // it is better to use an After Insert trigger.
    if( Trigger.IsAfter && Trigger.IsInsert )
    {
        // Move logic to other classes.
        BmcServiceDeskInciditeHanlder.checkAttachmentAdded(Trigger.new);
    }
}

// New class to handle business logic
public class BmcServiceDeskInciditeHanlder()
{
    // Function to check if attacments have been added.
    public static void checkAttachmentAdded(List<Attachment> attachments)
    {
        Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> serviceDeskIncidents = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>()
        // Collect the Parent Ids to be used later to query the BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c sObject record(s)
        for(Attachment a : attachments)
        {
            parentIds.add(a.ParentId);
        }

        // Query records in a for loop (this is more efficient)
        for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c incident : [SELECT Id, Attachment_Added__c FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c WHERE Id IN :parentIds])
        {
            incident.Attachment_Added__c = true;
            // Add records to a List so they can be Bulk updated.
            serviceDeskIncidents.add(incident);
        }

        // Update all records at once.
        update serviceDeskIncidents;
    }
}
```

Test class to cover *one* scenario.  Remember you should cover multiple scenarios. ex: No Attachment added, Attachment Added, Bulk upload (200 or so) inserted (for testing governor limits)

```
@isTest
public class CheckAttachmentTest {
    public static void testAttachment(){
        // Create BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c sObject for testing.
        BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c incident = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(Name='Test Incident');
        // Insert into database
        insert incident;

        // Create attachment object for testing.
        Attachment att = new Attachment();
        Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Test Data'); 
        att.Name = 'Unit Test Attachment';
        att.Body =  b;
        att.ParentID =  incident.Id;// Associate Attachment with BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c record.
        att.ContentType = 'application/msword';
        att.Description = 'Test, please disregard';
        att.IsPrivate = false;
        insert att;

        // Query BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c records.
        List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> bmcIncidents =[select Attachment_Added__c from BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c where Id = :incident.id];

        // Assert records are returned
        System.assertEquals(1, bmcIncidents.size());
        // Assert the Attachment_Added__c field was set properly.
        System.assertEquals(true, bmcIncidents[0].Attachment_Added__c);
    }
}
```

[Apex Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)